# Detection of multiple objects (using OpenCV)

Tags: object-detection

I want to find multiple objects in a scene (objects look the same, but may differ in scale, and rotation and I don´t know what the object to be detected will be). I have implemented the following idea, based on the featuredetectors in OpenCV, which works:

```
detect and compute keypoints from the object
for i < max_objects_todetect; i++
     1. detect and compute keypoints from the whole scene
     2. match scene and object keypoints with Flannmatcher
     3. use findHomography/Ransac to compute the boundingbox of the first object (object which hast the most keypoints in the scene with multiple objects)
     4. set the pixel in the scene, which are within the computed boundingbox to 0, -> in the next loopcycle there are no keypoints for this object to detect anymore.
```

The Problem with this implementation is that I need to compute the keypoints for the scene multiple times which needs alot of computing time (250ms). Does anyone has a better idea for detecting multiple objects?

Thanks Drian

Comment: What detector and descriptor are you using?

Comment: Using SURF detector and descriptor right now

Comment: May be you should use ORB instead, its faster than SURF. But I don't know how accurate it is for your images.

Answer (score 0):

Hello togehter I tried ORB which is indeed faster and I will try Akaze.

While testing ORB I have encouterd following problem:

While chaning the size of my picture doesn´t affect the detected keypoints in Surf (finds the same keypoints in the small and in the big picture (in the linked picture right)), it affects the keypoints detected by ORB. In the small picute i´m not able to find these keypoints. I tried to experiment with the ORB parameters but couldn´t make it work.

Picture: http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/bildermaf6d3zt.png

SURF:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SURF> detector = cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(100);
```

ORB:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> detector = cv::ORB::create( 1500,  1.05f,16, 31, 0, 2, ORB::HARRIS_SCORE, 2, 10);
```

Do you know if, and how it´s possible to detect the same keypoints independent of the size of the pictures?

Greetings Drian

Comment: How does it matter if it detects same key points independent of the size or not? If you are detecting multiple objects and setting the pixels for them to 0, if the object detection is correct, independent of the size, it doesn't matter, in my opinion.

Comment: When I want to detect the small part in the big part i´m not able to find the object with ORB, cause i have no keypoints in the small picture detected by ORB, When I use SURF instead i have keypoints and i´m able to detect the Object.

Comment: That is indeed a problem. You should try playing with the parameters, in particular `scaleFactor` and `patchSize`. If that doesn't work, try using `BRISK` instead for detection and `Opponent BRISK` for description. The detector should give you a lot of `Keypoints` so you might want to filter the matches from the descriptors before estimating the homography.